# Women and Parshas Zachor

Tags: four-parshiot, halacha, women

Are women Halachically responsible to hear the reading of Parshas Zachor?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/53913/have-women-accepted-zachor-on-themselves

Comment: See also my answer to that question: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/73294/1516

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Chinuch* 603 says women are not obligated in the active biblical *mitzva* of remembering what *Amalek* did, and in 605 says that the details of the "don't forget" *mitzva* were covered in 603, which *Minchas Chinuch* (in 603) says "seems a little" to imply that they're exempt from that one, too. However, *MC* himself (in 603) seems to decide that they *are* obligated in both the *mitzvos*.

Note, though, that besides the biblical *mitzvos*, there's a rabbinic enactment of reading the four *parashiyos*. I don't know the parameters of this obligation, but I'd assume that it's either on the *tzibur* as a whole or, at least, not on women.

Rabbi Menachem Greenblatt (St. Louis, Mo.) mentioned today that, although they should make every attempt to listen [and his *shul* has a second reading for them], women can rely on those who say they are exempt. I trust I'm quoting him correctly, but you're encouraged to ask him yourselves to be sure. As always, for practical *halacha*, [CYLOR](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/CYLOR).

Answer (score 3):

I think this might be a daas yachid, but i remember hearing in shiur that the Chofetz Chaim told his sister(s?) that they need not go to shul to hear it, since they were patur. this because they were not chayiv in "timche et zecher Amalek", which is the end goal of remembering.

Comment: Interesting STORY where is it said?

Comment: Not a yachid.. also chinuch...